# using openstack-client, interfaces with static IPs do not automatically come up

Tags: openstack, nic, static-ip-address

I have come at this a couple of ways, defining a `port` first, or assigning the static IPs after the instance is created, but I always have the same issue, the interface exists, but it is not up.

I can log in to the instance and configure it with `ip addr add 10.10.10.10/24 dev ensX && ip link set ensX up` and then it is able to communicate with other instances on the same subnet, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to make this happen automatically.

For example:

```sh
openstack server create -f value -c id --wait --nic net-id=90d79af5-5f54-4055-9e51-1f796fd2957a --nic net-id=bdef0023-176d-4be3-9e0d-135bef6034da,v4-fixed-ip=10.10.10.10 --flavor m1.medium --image 0a213f2f-3a83-4518-b35e-d478259d74d9 --key-name mypubkey testserver
```

Where the network is configured for subnet `10.10.10.0/24` and with DHCP either enabled *or* disabled.

I also tried creating a port first and then using `--port` instead, but I get the same results.

Any tips on what I'm missing? I'm running openstackclient==4.0.0 and python-openstackclient==5.2.0 on ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my issue is due to Ubuntu 18.04 and `netplan`. I decided I had two ways I could get around my issue:

1. Configure `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` with ansible.
2. Create a custom base image using `ifupdown` instead of `netplan`.

I decided not to go against the standard for Ubuntu 18.04 and just configure the interfaces post-build.

Comment: do you have used an ubuntu cloud image (https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/)? This should get the network-configuration from openstack over cloud-init.

Comment: @Tobias you know, I used the default Ubuntu image offered by my provider, but I never did try importing the latest vanilla image directly from the Ubuntu cloud images. I’ll try that today! Thanks.